# Al ingresar los datos en el formulario, crea el usuario pero no redirige a la página puesta con un parámetro

Tags: php

Cuando meto los datos en el formulario, me crea el usuario, pero no me redirige a la página que le pongo con el parámetro *nombre*.

Registro.php:

```
require_once("plantillas/inicio-html.inc.php");
include_once "app/Usuario.inc.php";
include_once "app/ValidadorRegistro.inc.php";
include_once "app/Conexion.inc.php";
include_once "app/RepositorioUsuario.inc.php";
include_once "app/Redireccion.inc.php";


if (isset($_POST["enviar"])){
    Conexion::abrir_conexion();

    $validador = new ValidadorRegistro($_POST["nombre"], $_POST["email"], $_POST["clave1"], $_POST["clave2"], Conexion :: obtener_conexion());

    if ($validador -> registro_valido()){
        $usuario = new Usuario('', $validador-> obtener_nombre(), $validador -> obtener_email(), password_hash($validador -> obtener_clave(), PASSWORD_DEFAULT), '', '');
        $usuario_insertado = RepositorioUsuario :: insertar_usuario(Conexion :: obtener_conexion(), $usuario);

        if ($usuario_insertado){
            //Redirigir al registro-correcto
            Redireccion::redirigir(RUTA_REGISTRO_CORRECTO.'?nombre='.$usuario -> obtener_nombre());
        }
    }

    Conexion::cerrar_conexion();
}
?>
<div class="card-body">
                    <form role="form" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>">
                        <?php
                            if(isset($_POST["enviar"])){
                                include_once "plantillas/registro_validado.inc.php";
                            }else{
                                include_once "plantillas/registro_vacio.inc.php";
                            }
                        ?>
                    </form>
                </div>
```

config.php (este archivo ya esta incluido en algún otro de los archivos):

```
define("SERVIDOR", "http://localhost:8080/prueba");
define("RUTA_REGISTRO", SERVIDOR."/registro.php");
define("RUTA_REGISTRO_CORRECTO", SERVIDOR."/registro_correcto.php");
define("RUTA_LOGIN", SERVIDOR."/login.php")
```

registro_correcto.php:

```
if (isset($_GET['nombre']) && !empty($_GET['nombre'])){
    $nombre = $_GET['nombre'];
}else{
    Redireccion::redirigir(SERVIDOR);
}
```

> Creo que no hace falta ningún código más, ya que lo que he añadido para la redirección está ahí.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucion en registro.php:

```
if (isset($usuario_insertado)){
            if (headers_sent()) {
                // las cabeceras ya se han enviado, no intentar añadir una nueva
                echo "Cabeceras ya enviadas";
            }
            else {
                // es posible añadir nuevas cabeceras HTTP
                echo "posible añadir nuevas";
               Redireccion::redirigir("http://localhost:8080/prueba/registro_correcto.php?dni=".$usuario -> obtener_dni());

            }
            //Redirigir al registro-correcto
            
        }
```