# Problemas con Redireccionamiento y headers_sent

Tags: php, redirección

Estoy intentando borrar una linea y que despues de borrar la linea se rediriga a la pagina principal, pero no puedo entrar a redirigirla.

Si lo establezco asi se me queda dentro del if en donde se ve "no se ha redirigido"

```
<form method="POST" action="">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="borrar_linea_economia" value="<?php $l_economia['id_factura'] ?>">
                                    <input type="submit" id="btn-basura" value="Eliminar">
                                </form>
                                <?php
                                if (isset($_POST['borrar_linea_economia'])){
                                    RepositorioEconomia::borrar_economia_id(Conexion::obtener_conexion(),$l_economia['id_factura']);
                                    if (headers_sent()) {
                                    // las cabeceras ya se han enviado, no intentar añadir una nueva
                                        echo "No se ha redirigido";
                                    } else {
                                        Redireccion::redirigir("http://localhost:8080/prueba/clientes/clientes.php");

                                    }
```

Si lo establezco asi me sale el siguiente error:

```
if (isset($_POST['borrar_linea_economia'])){
                                    RepositorioEconomia::borrar_economia_id(Conexion::obtener_conexion(),$l_economia['id_factura']);
                                    
                                        Redireccion::redirigir("http://localhost:8080/prueba/clientes/clientes.php");
                                }
```

Aqui el error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En este otro post lo solucione con la primera ocpion pero ahora nose por que no puedo y no encuentro la solucion.

[Problemas en redirección PHP](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/543644/problemas-en-redirecci%c3%b3n-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Claramente no has leído el manual.
la redirecion en php se hace por medio de las cabeceras, estas se envian al navegador antes del contenido de la pagina.

si hay algo excapado antes de modificar las cabeceras estas no se escribiran, por ende no funcionará.

no debe haber nada, ni un espacio antes de una llamada a header() donde escribes las cabeceras.

por eso se esta quedando pegado pues el id esta despues de etiquetas html que ya envias al navegador.

cuando quieras rerireccionar y ya has mandado cabeceras o un arespuesta http al clinete debes usar javascript en lugar de php.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedes ver con esta imagen de referencia, los header se generan antes del body, por consiguiente no puedes modificarlos una ves escapado algo a la pagina html

cuando sucede esto lo mejor es usar una redireccion via javascript.
por ejemplo:

```
 <form method="POST" action="">
 <input type="hidden" name="borrar_linea_economia" value="<?php $l_economia['id_factura'] ?>">
 <input type="submit" id="btn-basura" value="Eliminar">
 </form>
<?php
 if (isset($_POST['borrar_linea_economia'])){
 RepositorioEconomia::borrar_economia_id(Conexion::obtener_conexion(),$l_economia['id_factura']);
    ?>
    <scritp>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
       window.location='http://localhost:8080/prueba/clientes/clientes.php';
    }, false);
    </scritp>
    <?php exit();?>
```

Comment: Lo he añadido y funciona perfectamente, tengo nulos conocimientos en javascript pero buscare informacion acerca de ello ya que establecer la cabecera en ese redireccionamiento al pricipio en este caso no me es posible

Comment: para poder hacerlo debiese usar clases, por ejemplo una clase que te arme el html y retorne los datos, y allí si podrías modificar las cabeceras aun en el procesamiento pues no escapas nada hasta que lo indiques

Comment: Lo probare, gracias por la ayuda e informacion.